# Getting error Invalid type for parameter Item, value: type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'> while loading S3 to DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am new to AWS and learning. I have a JSON file with details of employees in S3 folder. Wrote a Lambda function with PYTHON 3.6 to load DynamoDB table XXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-Employees when the JSON file is uploaded to S3. All setups have been done with policy and roles to access CloudwatchLog, S3 and DynamoDB. Log file gives the error below. It appears that the issue is the file is a dictionary format like [] and the put_item expects string.. not sure.

(empid is the primary key)

Reviewed code and researched issue in google and AWS forums

```
import boto3

import json

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,   Key=json_file_name)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    #print(jsonFileReader)
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    #print(jsonDict)
    table = dynamodb.Table('XXXXXX-YYYYY-ZZZZZZ-Employees')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)    
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

Expected result: DynamoDB table loaded with JSON file data
Actual Result: getting error in cloudwatchlog:

Invalid type for parameter Item, value: [{'empid': 10004, 'email': 'test1@email.com', 'firstname': 'John5', 'lastname': 'Smith5', 'location': 'ABCD-B207', 'mobile': '123-456-7890', 'work': '098-765-4321', 'site': 'ABCD'}, {'empid': 10005, 'email': 'test1@email.com', 'firstname': 'John6',................. '}], type: , valid types:

Comment: What is a sample line from the S3 object? What is the content of `jsonDict`?

Comment: Sample line: {'empid': 10004, 'email': 'test1@email.com', 'firstname': 'John5', 'lastname': 'Smith5', 'location': 'ABCD-B207', 'mobile': '123-456-7890', 'work': '098-765-4321', 'site': 'ABCD'}

Comment: Please Edit your question to include the examples, rather than putting them in a comment.

Comment: Contents of jsonDict is mentioned above, starting with a square bracket. [{'empid': 10004, 'email': 'test1@email.com', 'firstname': 'John5', 'lastname': 'Smith5', 'location': 'ABCD-B207', 'mobile': '123-456-7890', 'work': '098-765-4321', 'site': 'ABCD'}, {'empid': 10005, 'email': 'test1@email.com', 'firstname': 'John6',................. '}], ...... many such lines. Basically, I am trying to load employee data in JSON format to DynamoDB employee table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your programming is reading **the entire file** into `jsonDict`. You are then attempting to **insert one item** using the dictionary.

Instead, you should extract one line at a time, then use `put_item()` to insert one item. Repeat for each line.

Something like this might be possible:

```
jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
table = dynamodb.Table('XXXXXX-YYYYY-ZZZZZZ-Employees')
for item in jsonDict:
    table.put_item(Item=item)
```

Comment: It worked. I also learned importance of indenting in Python. I appreciate your time